# Visual Studio for Mac connection to remote MS SQL Server failed

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac 2017 on macOS Sierra with Microsoft EntityframeworkCore and I'm trying to connect to a remote MS SQL Server.
If I start the project in Visual Studio on my Windows machine, everything works fine. But the same project on my Mac tells me "A call to SSPI failed" when I try to get data from the SQL Server. I can connect to the SQL Server using the "Oracle SQL Developer" tool on my Mac. So the issue is somewhere in Visual Studio.

The connection string: `Server=MySQLServer.domain.de;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=***;`

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I have to update my MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 to Service Pack 3. Otherwise .Net Core cannot connect: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/666